# Ctrl-C in tmux closing window pane but not exiting tail -F

Tags: tmux

I have the following script to start and setup tmux based on my dev environment:

```
#!/bin/bash

ENV="Test"
TMUX_SESSION="${ENV}LogMonSes"
TMUX_WINDOW="${ENV}LogMonWin"

tmux new-session -d -n "$TMUX_WINDOW" -s "$TMUX_SESSION" "ssh server1 tail -F /var/log/tomcat/application.log"
tmux split-window -v "ssh server2 sudo tail -F /var/log/postgresql/postgresql.log"
tmux attach-session -d -t "$TMUX_SESSION"
```

When I want to exit tmux I hit Control-C to kill tail. This appears to close the pane but does not kill the tail process. If I log back into the server I see a bunch of tail processes that have not been killed and I am forced to do it manually. Any ideas on how to let the Control-C kill the tail processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Problem" is with ssh - not tmux.

See [Why does my remote process still run after killing an ssh session?](https://superuser.com/questions/20679/why-does-my-remote-process-still-run-after-killing-an-ssh-session)

Added `-t` to ssh and now everything works great:

```
tmux new-session -d -n "$TMUX_WINDOW" -s "$TMUX_SESSION" "ssh -t server1 tail -F /var/log/tomcat/application.log"
tmux split-window -v "ssh -t server2 sudo tail -F /var/log/postgresql/postgresql.log"
tmux attach-session -d -t "$TMUX_SESSION"
```